# How to group by with created_at in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I my app i want to fetch all orders group by date at `created_at` field in laravel

but it is timestamp all date are same but time is different i want to get all data on only date wise not time

but group by not working i google it but not found any proper solution.

so how can we do that any body help thanks in advance

this is the result
http://prntscr.com/nr8xjm

```
 $query = DB::table('tms_driver');
 $query->join('tms_booking', 'tms_driver.dv_id', '=', 'tms_booking.dv_id');
 $query->where('tms_booking.dv_id', $request->id);
 $query->where('tms_booking.tms_booking_status', '1');
 $query->orderBy('tms_booking.tms_booking_id', 'DESC');
 $query->groupBy('tms_booking.created_at');
 $query->select('tms_booking.created_at as booking_date','tms_booking.total_paid', DB::raw('count(tms_booking.tms_booking_id) as total_booking'));
 $performances = $query->get();
```

Comment: but created_at is a timestamp. what you expect to see? maybe you want group by year, month or day?

Comment: yes it is timestamp and group by day

Answer (score 1):

you can group by date this way

```
->groupBy(DB::raw('Date(tms_booking.created_at)'))
```

or use Carbon in closure, for example

```
->groupBy(function ($item) {
        return Carbon::parse($item->created_at)->format('Y-m-d');
})
```